# How to work with graphic tablet in Java?

Tags: java, tablet

Couple of weeks ago I have bought graphic tablet Wacom Bamboo. I want to develop small java application that can capture user's actions, process it and draw appropriate picture. Does anyone know how to get specific parameters of stylus, such as power of pressure, in Java?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should take a look at: [JTablet](http://jtablet.cellosoft.com/). Last time I checked (which was admittedly long ago) it was the only library that supported tablets. It is used in the popular oekaki java applets, so it's a proven library.

Answer (score 0):

JTablet is based on JPen

just tried JPen, it half-works

maybe you'll have more luck

http://jpen.sourceforge.net/html-home/aux-newJPenHome/JPenExample.java