# JPen alternative for Java program

Tags: java, input, tablet, wacom

I want to develop a small Java program using some input like the pen of a Wacom graphictablet and found only the very active JPen project but are there some more possible alternatives without JNI or JNA (without any additional needed dll files), a pure Java implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [JTablet](http://jtablet.cellosoft.com/). From another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9373160/how-to-work-with-graphic-tablet-in-java) thread.

Comment: seems very outdated, latest version is from 2010 and development was stopped.

Answer (score 0):

It seems JPen moved to GitHub and this might be the best solution at the moment.

The other alternative solutions are not developed and maintained anymore.

https://github.com/nicarran/jpen